# How to correct refer to according normalized entity data in Redux Reducer

Tags: redux, reducers, normalizr

All:

I am pretty new to redux reducer, most answers point to normalizr.js. Taking example like:

```
const blogPosts = [
    {
        id : "post1",
        author : {username : "user1", name : "User 1"},
        body : "......",
        comments : [
            {
                id : "comment1",
                author : {username : "user2", name : "User 2"},
                comment : ".....",
            },
            {
                id : "comment2",
                author : {username : "user3", name : "User 3"},
                comment : ".....",
            }
        ]    
    },
    {
        id : "post2",
        author : {username : "user2", name : "User 2"},
        body : "......",
        comments : [
            {
                id : "comment3",
                author : {username : "user3", name : "User 3"},
                comment : ".....",
            },
            {
                id : "comment4",
                author : {username : "user1", name : "User 1"},
                comment : ".....",
            },
            {
                id : "comment5",
                author : {username : "user3", name : "User 3"},
                comment : ".....",
            }
        ]    
    }
    // and repeat many times
]
```

I define schema as below:

```
var authorSchm = new schema.Entity("authors", {}, {idAttribute: "username"});
var commentSchm = new schema.Entity("comments", {author:authorSchm})
var commentList = [commentSchm];
var postSchm = new schema.Entity("posts", {author:authorSchm, comments:commentList});
var postList = [postSchm];


var normalizedData = normalize(blogPosts, postList);
console.log(JSON.stringify(normalizedData, null, 4));
```

And I get result like:

```
{
    "entities": {
        "authors": {
            "user1": {
                "username": "user1",
                "name": "User 1"
            },
            "user2": {
                "username": "user2",
                "name": "User 2"
            },
            "user3": {
                "username": "user3",
                "name": "User 3"
            }
        },
        "comments": {
            "comment1": {
                "id": "comment1",
                "author": "user2",
                "comment": "....."
            },
            "comment2": {
                "id": "comment2",
                "author": "user3",
                "comment": "....."
            },
            "comment3": {
                "id": "comment3",
                "author": "user3",
                "comment": "....."
            },
            "comment4": {
                "id": "comment4",
                "author": "user1",
                "comment": "....."
            },
            "comment5": {
                "id": "comment5",
                "author": "user3",
                "comment": "....."
            }
        },
        "posts": {
            "post1": {
                "id": "post1",
                "author": "user1",
                "body": "......",
                "comments": [
                    "comment1",
                    "comment2"
                ]
            },
            "post2": {
                "id": "post2",
                "author": "user2",
                "body": "......",
                "comments": [
                    "comment3",
                    "comment4",
                    "comment5"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "result": [
        "post1",
        "post2"
    ]
}
```

I wonder how do I use this normalized data in Redux reducer and combineReducers?
And **how do I know which entity I should go to get next level data according to the reference string**( for example: when I get "post1", how do I know I should go to posts entity to get post1 object and inside post1 object, how to do that for those comment1, comment2.. )

Answer (score 0):

Any answer to this is going to be largely subjective and dependent on your specific application and use-case. For a generic and recommended approach, check out the official [example](https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr/tree/master/examples/redux). Here's what the [combineReducers](https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr/blob/master/examples/redux/src/redux/reducer.js) looks like.

Comment: Thanks, could you talk a lil bit detail according to my blogposts example as subjective as u can?